# Foreign Key Constraint Error When Save Changes To Database

Tags: c#, .net

I have this error when I use the create function in my application:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Books_dbo_Genres_GenreId'

I tried to change the db.savechanges code but it did not work.

Here is a link to my project code:

```
 // POST: Book/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel bookVM)
        {
            var book = new Book
            {
                Author = bookVM.Book.Author,
                Availablity = bookVM.Book.Availablity,
                DateAdded = bookVM.Book.DateAdded,
                Description = bookVM.Book.Description,
                Genre= bookVM.Book.Genre,
                ImageUrl = bookVM.Book.ImageUrl,
                ISBN = bookVM.Book.ISBN,
                Pages = bookVM.Book.Pages,
                Currency = bookVM.Book.Currency,
                ProductDimensions = bookVM.Book.ProductDimensions,
                PublicationDate = bookVM.Book.PublicationDate,
                Title = bookVM.Book.Title
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Books.Add(book);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var model = new BookViewModel
            {
                Book = book,
                Genres = db.Genres.ToList()
            };

            bookVM.Genres = db.Genres.ToList();
            return View(bookVM);
        }
```

See above link for error.

Comment: You need to include a sample of the failing code in the question.  Your google drive link gives access denied when I visit it.

Comment: can you please take a look? I attached the code. If you run the application and click on admin -> book -> create -> then fill out the information and click submit i have that error in the image link.  https://i.imgur.com/fL6AfHB.png

Comment: Please place your code **in the question**.  To preserve your questions long-term value, code should be in the question; links go bad over time, or the content on those links can be modified.  The question should contain everything needed to understand and answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your value genres in book object is having proper data or null value.

Comment: can you please take a look? I attached the code. If you run the application and click on admin -> book -> create -> then fill out the information and click submit i have that error in the image link.

Comment: You should determine what value you are using for the genre.  You can use a breakpoint at the ModelState.IsValid line and check the Genre value at that point.  The value is like either null, or not a valid value in your Genre table.

Comment: @grax i tried so many scenario. Can you please take a look at my code and let me know what mistake i made?

Comment: What value do you see for Genre when you get to ModelState.IsValid?

Comment: @grax 
it gives me this error The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Books_dbo_Genres_GenreId' and points to db.savechanges()

Comment: You need to read up on how to set break points so that you can stop the code execution on the ModelState.IsValid line and check the value. Or you could use debug tools in your web browser to see what value is being sent for Genre.   Or you could temporarily remove the foreign key constraint on the book table and see what value ends up in the genre column

Comment: @grax I am new to this, Can you please download the code and try it?

Comment: Sorry, learning how to use debug tools will benefit you far more than me telling you precisely how to fix it.